# Using csv as PowerShell script parameter

Tags: string, powershell, csv, param

I trying to write a PowerShell script (learning at the same time).

I have following named parameters

```
param([String] $Workspace = $pwd,
      [String] $Files     = "*",
      [String] $Locales   = "de,es,fr,it,nl,pt_BR,ru",
      [String] $Exception = "TINP_D=TIGF,TIN_F=TIGD",
      [Switch] $Verbose,
      [Switch] $Whatif)
```

Lets say for the $Locales I am using split to loop through each locale with

```
foreach ($locale in $Locales.split(",")) {
```

So far so good. The problem starts when I specify a list of locales on command without double quotes, as it is detected as array of string and it becomes "de es fr" which in return breaks my code as it expects a CSV string.

And same goes for $Exception parameter but for that I split on comma then on equals sign.

Any Ideas, what should I be doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are more solutions, the easiest one is to alter the parameter so that it is array of strings

```
[String[]] $Locales   = ('de', 'es', ...)
```

And then just iterate the array

```
foreach ($locale in $Locales)
```

Comment: The problem with this approach was that the param list is already comma separated and defining default array values with comma breaks the param list

Comment: +1 Indeed, usually you specify actual string arrays to functions/cmdlets.